# What is this character " " JavaScript inserts into input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Already solved -- please see answer**

---

I can't even identify this character, and on Chrome it's invisible, whereas on Firefox it looks like this: [image: this]

This character is inserted into the HTML input field when `on.keydown` I fade an input into view and insert the alphanumeric-character pressed, plus set the cursor to after the alphanumeric-character.

The main code that does this is

```
      $searchtext.val(String.fromCharCode(e).toLowerCase())
      .setCursorPosition($searchtext.val().length);
      $search.fadeIn(200);
```

`e` in `fromCharCode(e)` is the `keyChar` pressed and passed to the JS function as a parameter (I can show the whole code if it helps but I don't think the issue is occurring elsewhere but that block of code).

The `setCurrentPosition()` is a func like this:

```
// extending the jQuery prototype with setCursorPosition
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
  this.each(function(index, elem) {
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
      elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
    }
  });
  return this;
};
```

**EDIT**
As you see in the question title, the character can't even be used on Stack.  When I copy paste it in Firefox here into the Stack question, it appears, but only until I save.  If I leave the question as a draft and open Stack on Chrome, the character is replaced with "�"

Comment: You sure `e` isn't the *keydown* event object?

Comment: Doh!   You're absolutely right, `e` is the event, and I should be using `String.fromCharCode(e.which)`.  If you submit as answer, I'll mark correct.   Thank you.

Comment: You should probably delete this question given *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.* and also because some of us just read the whole thing  to find out you solved it already ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Phil pointed out in the comments of my question, I was using `e` event instead of the event's keyCode char via `e.which`.

With that, I am assuming the character that was being inserted was a representation of a JS object.